# Getting error in writing a background process for iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, cydia

For my app i want to make a background process so i did.
But now when try to load the process by script in postinst like this
`/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.dev.app`.

i am getting error msg:

> Could not open job overrides database at: /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist: 2: No such file or directory

can anyone please help me to get rid of this?

### Edit:

Debian `postinst` script:

```sh
chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.dev.app.plist
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.dev.app.plist
```

Comment: Show us your whole postinst script

Comment: it is Line 1.(chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.dev.app.plist)
      Line 2.(launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.dev.app.plist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this error message, too.

If you look on your phone's filesystem (e.g. login with `ssh`), I bet you don't have a folder at `/private/var/db/launchd.db`.

Just because iOS can't find that database file doesn't mean your daemon isn't loaded (or unloaded).  Use the `ps -Aef` command at the command line (logged into the phone) to check whether your daemon process is running or not.

Inside your daemon's plist file (e.g. `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mycompany.mydaemon.plist`), you can set a **Disabled** flag (but, you probably won't).  The `overrides.plist` file can override the Disabled setting from your daemon's plist file.

My guess is that this is primarily an OS X feature, and not commonly used by iOS, which shares much of the same codebase.

### Edit:

If you *really* feel the need to get rid of the message, it looks like simply creating that directory will get rid of it.  So, you could add something like this in your `postinst` script, before calling `launchctl`:

```sh
mkdir -p /var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd
```

Comment: You are right After listing running processes i get to know that my process is running successfully but why this is happening now because before 6 months when i created a background process like that, it didn't show any error like that. And i also don't have /var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd. Thanks again for your help

Comment: iOS 7 might be different. I don't have an older, jailbroken iOS device available right now, but Apple may have either changed their code, or removed extra directories that aren't "needed" on iOS, causing this message to **start** appearing.